# My textbox does not update

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, tcplistener

I'm using this code in my TCP socket server program, using WinForms

```
try
{
    Stream s = new NetworkStream(soc);
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s);
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(s);
    sw.AutoFlush = true;
    //label_status.Text = "Start Conversation";
    SettextLabel("Start Conversation.....");
    while (true)
    {    
        string msg = sr.ReadLine();
        SettextRecieveMassage(msg);
    }

}



private void SettextRecieveMassage(string text)
{
    if (this.rtxt_RecieveMassage.InvokeRequired)
    {
        SetTextCallBack d = new SetTextCallBack(SettextRecieveMassage);
        this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
    }
    else
    {
        rtxt_RecieveMassage.Text += text;
    }
}
```

When I connect the client to my server program and send the message, the textbox doesn't show the text then but after I close the connection at my client side, all the messages I've sent will show in the textbox.

So, why doesn't my textbox update?

Comment: Add the line `rtxt_RecieveMassage.Refresh()` after you change the the text!

Comment: @No1_Melman I still got the same result.Any other solution?

Comment: Well, I can tell you that the problem is that you're not updating your UI thread, i don't think your method to set the text is correct, but I can't quite remember off the top of my head what it should be

Comment: @No1_Melman but The textbox update the massage after client just close( Seems like it Recieve massage just before client close.)

Comment: try calling `Application.DoEvents();` after `SettextRecieveMassage(msg);`

Comment: @No1_Melman Yes, I am.

Comment: doesn't sockets have a callback for when it receives a message?